# MS SQL передать параметры выборки в код Python

Tags: python, sql-server

Есть база, в ней есть таблица, пишу триггер который при обновлении в таблице выполняет некий код Python3. Уже делал подобное некоторое время назад но забыл как передавать в код Python значение из нужной колонки. Кажись что-то связано с pandas для парсинга таблицы.

Пример.
Есть таблица Clients:

```
Account_number  Amount  mgd_uniq  Name  Code  CreateAt
123456789       177.50  79842     NULL  NULL  2021-09-14 16:41:51
```

При update столбцов `Name` и `Code` хочу забирать значение `Amount` и использовать его в следующем примере кода:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Clients_UPDATE
ON Clients
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import requests

s = requests.Session()

#code
#code
#code
 
payload = {
    "amount": amount,
    }
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",   
    }
sub_amount = s.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)';
END
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @Духсообщества добавил пример

Answer (score 0):

Вспомнил зачем панда) Чтобы распарсить выборку из панда.датафрейм:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Clients_UPDATE
ON Clients
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Input_Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT Amount FROM Clients where id = (SELECT MAX(id) from Clients)';
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
@language = N'Python',
@script = N'
import requests
import pandas

s = requests.Session()

#code
#code
#code
 
payload = {
    "amount": int(some_data.loc[0].at["Amount"]),
    }
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",   
    }
sub_amount = s.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
',
@input_data_1 = @Input_Query,
@input_data_1_name = N'some_data';
END
```